# How do I get the registration or update date for Azure Notification Hub registrations?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

In my Xamarin app, every time the app launches, it registers or updates with the Azure Notification Hub.

In my Azure Hub dashboard, I can see the number of registrations by date.

Using the GetAllRegistrationsAsync method returns a list of [RegistrationDescription class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.registrationdescription?view=azure-dotnet) objects, but these objects have no timestamp or "lastChangedDate" field.

How can I programmatically find out when the registrations were made or updated?